# Bad allocation error when populating std::vector

Tags: c++, file-io, vector

I am reading three large binary files (each one c.180Mb) into a std::vector as follows:

```
m_ifStream.open("myfile.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

if (m_ifStream)
{
    //Obtain input stream length
    m_ifStream.seekg (0, ios::end);
    streamLength = (size_t)(m_ifStream.tellg());
    m_ifStream.seekg (0, ios::beg);

    //Reserve doesn't work around the problem, may be more efficient though...
    //m_buffer = new vector<unsigned char>();
    //m_buffer->reserve(streamLength);

    //Next line sometimes results in bad_alloc when reading a large file
    m_buffer = new vector<unsigned char>((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(m_ifStream)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
}
```

The call to populate the vector fails, throwing a "bad allocation" exception.

The population sometimes fails when reading the first file; at other times it fails on the second or the third.  I am using Visual Studio 2010 and compiling my code as 32-bit, which should be able to address up to 2Gb.  I am running on a machine with 16Gb RAM, with at least 10Gb free, so a lack of available memory is not the issue.  The error occurs in both debug and release configurations.

Pre-allocating memory with `reserve` does not help.

The `max_size` property of the vector returns 2^32, so it doesn't appear to be a limitation in the container.

The code is fine with a large number of smaller files with combined size > 180Mb, causing me to think that my code is hitting a boundary.

Is there an accepted way to populate a vector from a large input file?  I wanted to avoid iterating over each byte in the file, and had thought that using `istreambuf_iterator`  would be optimised for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing more work and allocating more memory than you need.

First remove the pointer, it adds nothing

```
vector<char> m_buffer;
```

Then call resize (not reserve) to the correct size

```
m_buffer.resize(streamLength);
```

If you are going to run out of memory this is when it will happen.

Finally read the data directly into the vector, don't use a streambuf_iterator, which does who knows what behind the scenes

```
m_ifStream.read(&m_buffer[0], streamLength);
```

The main benefit here is that you only allocate one vector (your code had two vectors one of which got copied on top of the other) and secondly you've removed all the fluff and just left the two basic operations, allocate the memory, read the file.

Comment: Should resize generally be favoured over reserve?

Comment: @pdm2011 No because they do different things. reserve allocates memory but does not resize the vector, resize does resize the vector (which obviously implies allocating memory). In your code the vector was being implicitly resized by the following operations, in my code I need to explicitly resize the vector because I'm reading into it directly, so it has to be the right size before I do that.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I used your suggestions but unfortunately the same problem occurs, this time on fourth call to resize.  My suspicion is heap corruption somewhere else in the code, but I haven't found anything incrimunating and the code is robust with a large number of smaller files.  I'm using a generated wrapper for marshalling between C# and unmanaged code which may be doing some excessive container copying - I'll try running it through a profiler and also see what effect a 64-bit build has.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have your call to `reserve()` have any effect on the actual reading, you should **not** create a temporary `std::vector<unsigned char>` and assign this temporary to the target vector. Instead, you` use something like

```
m_buffer->assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(m_ifStream),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Reading the file without reserving may fragment your memory in some way but I wouldn't expect that the program runs out of memory for a small file like yours (files with a couple a couple of GB can be considered large; 160MB isn't really large). If you know the size of the file, you are probably best off reading the file using the `read()` member, though:

```
m_buffer->resize(streamLength);
m_ifStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(m_buffer->data()), streamLength);
```

My personal guess is that the `std::bad_alloc` exceptions actually result from an error in determining the file's size. For example, I don't think that `std::size_t` is necessarily large enough to hold a `std::streamsize`. Also, there is no attempt made to verify that any of these operations are successful and if the stream couldn't be opened, `seekg()` will return `pos_type(-1)` which will translate into a rather large `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
m_buffer = new vector<unsigned char>();
m_buffer->reserve(streamLength);

//Next line sometimes results in bad_alloc when reading a large file
*m_buffer = vector<unsigned char>((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(m_ifStream)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
```

The first thing that strikes me is that you are overwriting an already pre-allocated area of a `vector`. There is clearly no point in doing "reserve", if you then create a new vector to overwrite that vector. It just means that you have to have space for BOTH these relatively large vectors.

I would start by changing `m_buffer` to not be a pointer to vector - that way, you don't have to call `new vector<unsigned char>` - it serves very little purpose to have a pointer to a vector [at best, you save some 16 bytes, if your have a vector that contains nothing].

Then remove the `reserve`. See how that goes.

Comment: This was actually what I was doing initially - I introduced the reserve as I had read that it might help.  I've edited the question to reflect this.